# SQL Server 2008 - Create a View With an Extra Column 'HasMutual'

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view

I am trying to create a View with SQL Server 2008 that can enable me to see if user a and b have mutual friends.

Use a and b are stored in a table called `Friendships` as Sender and Recipient with a `IsPending` column indicating if the friendship has been approved by the Recipient.

Anyway the main table is like this:

```
Sender | Recipient | IsPending
(Stored on a single row.)
```

How can I create a view that returns an extra column called `HasMutual` with a 0 if false or 1 if true?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you write a SELECT statement to do this?  Start simple and write a SELECT that shows which mutual friends a and b have.  From there, it should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I wish I was smart enough to figure out this query!*

*I can't believe the first two answers each got an up-vote.  And this is not trivial as Ben Thul has claimed!*

Since this is so difficult to solve with a single query, would you consider a different approach?

**How about a stored procedure that takes in a pair of users, and then lists out their mutual friends?**

(I'm assuming `IsPending = 1` means they aren't friends yet)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE find_mutual_friends
(
  @user1 varchar(255),
  @user2 varchar(255)
)
as 
SELECT
  Friends
FROM
(SELECT
  Friendships.Sender as Friends
FROM
  Friendships
WHERE
  Friendships.Recipient = @user1
  and Friendships.IsPending = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
  Friendships.Recipient as Friends
FROM
  Friendships
WHERE
  Friendships.Sender = @user1
  and Friendships.IsPending = 0) FriendsTempTable
WHERE
  FriendsTempTable.Friends in
(SELECT
  Friendships.Sender as Friends
FROM
  Friendships
WHERE
  Friendships.Recipient = @user2
  and Friendships.IsPending = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
  Friendships.Recipient as Friends
FROM
  Friendships
WHERE
  Friendships.Sender = @user2
  and Friendships.IsPending = 0)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already have a method that returns a list of mutual friends. But my whole idea is before using that method i'd like to check if HasMutual is true then I could fetch that list..

Comment: I see what you mean, but it would be a performance detriment anyway.  Usually, you are only dealing with the context of 2 people (i.e. Facebook), so just fetch the list, if rows returned = 0, then they have no mutual friends, else list the friends.  The view would be an extra database query.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW ViewName
AS

SELECT
        Sender , Recipient , IsPending, IsPending AS HasMutual
FROM    myTable
```